# Dont know what is wrong with this code. It doesnt work

Tags: php, html, checkbox

Hi can anyone tell me why this code doesnt work? i was following tutorial from

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4X4c4fRW2Q
unfortunately for me i cant seems to do as what he is doing. i only followed his tutorial till 17min. i adjusted some of his code but still are not able to produce what he produced at the 17min mark of the video.

Here is my code..

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
$queryDate = mysqli_select_db($connection, "car_request");
if (!$queryDate) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
?>






<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Our Company</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   body{
      font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size:14px;
      line-height: 1.6x;
      test-align:center ;
      }
      #wrapper{
          margin:0 auto;
          width:650px;
          text-align:left;
      }
      td{
          padding: 20px
      }
      thead{
          background: #D2E6EA;
      }
      </style>
</head>

<body>


 <div id="wrapper">

  <form action ="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"method="GET">
  <table width="100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
      <td>Police ID</td>
      <td>Role</td>
      <td>Name of Supervisor</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Time</td>
      <td>Type of vehicle</td>
      <td>Reasons</td>
      <td>&nbsp</td>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php while($row = $queryDate->fetch_assoc()){
  <tr>
      <td>echo $row['police_id']</td>
      <td> echo $row['role']</td>
      <td> echo $row['supervisor_name']</td>
      <td> echo $row['date']</td>
      <td> echo $row['time']</td>
      <td> echo $row['vehicle_type']</td>
      <td> echo $row['reasons']</td>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value=" echo $row['id'];">
      </tr>
  }
  ?>

  </tbody>
  </table>
  </form>



  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

and i would like to ask why is he able open up php in the html so many times. If anyone gets what i saying...

Cheers look forward for anyone who reply... :)

Comment: [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) requires 4 parameters, not 3. You never perform a query to get data for the table.

Comment: it echoes out an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\test\home.php on line 65" and i dont get it why it doesnt work it suppose to have a table with some records and a checkbox at the most right of the table at each row.

Comment: There is no query to your DB. All the code does is opening a connection and selecting the DB, but no actual SQL query is run.

Comment: ok i am sorry about that, i change the top part of the code to

$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "car_request");

if (!$db_select) {die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());}

$queryDate = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM request")


but the error is still there...

Comment: I assume you commented on the youtube video before posting here for help? Too specific.

Comment: no i didnt comment there and waitng for a reply would take ages

Answer (score 1):

Turn

```
<?php while($row = $queryDate->fetch_assoc()){
  <tr>
      <td>echo $row['police_id']</td>
      <td> echo $row['role']</td>
      <td> echo $row['supervisor_name']</td>
      <td> echo $row['date']</td>
      <td> echo $row['time']</td>
      <td> echo $row['vehicle_type']</td>
      <td> echo $row['reasons']</td>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value=" echo $row['id'];">
      </tr>
  }
  ?>
```

into

```
<?php while($row = $queryDate->fetch_assoc()){
  echo '
  <tr>
      <td>' . $row['police_id'] . '</td>
      <td>' . $row['role'] . '</td>
      <td>' . $row['supervisor_name'] . '</td>
      <td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>
      <td>' . $row['time'] . '</td>
      <td>' . $row['vehicle_type'] . '</td>
      <td>' . $row['reasons'] . '</td>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="' . $row['id'] . '"></td>
      </tr>';
  }
  ?>
```

You're mixing up HTML in PHP syntaxis, which (ofcourse) won't work ;)  P.s. you are missing a closing `</td>` in the last cell.

After re-checking your original question there's more missing (like the actual that should fetch the results). Since you're referring to the youtube video, mimicking shouldn't be that hard and StackOverflow shouldn't be needed to answer this question.

Comment: Hi sir,
i did what you told but i received 2 errors.

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\test\home.php on line 11

My line 11 is:       
$queryDate = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM request");

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\test\home.php on line 65  My line 65 is :<?php while($row = $queryDate->fetch_assoc()){

Comment: You also have to provide the mysqli link in the myqsli_query function when you're using the library procedural. The second parameter should be your query. See the docs on this as well: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php